# Search API Views - How to display facets on a views block?

Tags: blocks, search

I am using [Search Api Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Facet API](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) to achieve that.

I am trying to enable facets to a views block, or when calling a view programmatically, but unfortunately they are not displayed as expected.

However facets are correctly displayed on the page created under views interface:

[image]

I tried to create a block via views interface, and then adding it through blocks, but the facets block doesn't appear.

Either if a try to print the view programmatically this way:

```
$view = views_get_view('news_search_api_');
$view->set_display('page');
$preview = $view->preview('page');
print $preview;
```

The facets are not loaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on your theme; but this is an example of how to do it with 'Commons'

in > admin > Structure > Blocks

> Search for your facets and select the block you want them to go in .  ie 'Sidebar First'
>
> SAVE
>
> open your View > Page .
>
> under FORMAT change Show to 'Panel Fields'
>
> In Settings choose your Panel Layout from the list.  ie 'AT One Column' should display the above block example.

[image]

> And then still in the VIEW - making sure you are in the 'Page' display; otherwise you won't see this option.  Under 'Advanced' - you should now see under 'Exposed Form' the text 'Exposed form in block:'  - Change this to Yes.
>
> once you've added this to the view you'll now be able to 
>   go back to > structure > blocks.
>   And see the exposed form here to move to the block you wish.

This information should be enough to point you in the right direction.